# Interpreting glmer confidence interval in lme4

Tags: r, logistic-regression, confidence-interval

I ran the following commands:

```
m2=glmer(data=d,Acc.Factor~1+(1|Stim)+(1|Ss),family='binomial')  
conf2=confint(m2)
```

and I got the follwing confidance interval:

```
-0.8228540 0.03897298
```

now I want to convert the value of the confidance interval to the original units from logit units, and I am not sure what should I do. Should I just take each value and and raise to the power of ten?

```
[-0.822^10 0.0389^10]
```

Comment: Use `plogis` to calculate the inverse of the logit function. You can also use `boot::inv.logit`, but that just refers to `plogis` anyway.

Comment: It would also good to read up what the logit function actually is. It is _not_ just a log10. But that's beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: @Axeman Even if it were log10, OP's proposed back-transformation would be wrong.

Comment: logit(x)=log(x/(1-x)), so according to my understaning from this if logit(x)=a, than x=(10^a)/(1+10^a). and if we take a=-0.822 we get 0.2884. But when we use plogis(-0.822) we get 0.30533. can you explain the difference? thanks

Comment: the problem was the the logit is in base e. thank you all

Comment: I keep a non-computer-code derivation of the back-transformation in my personal notes: http://nutterb.github.io/ItCanBeShown/logistic-regression.html#retrieving-the-modelled-probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function that converts to the original values is plogis(). it implements invlogit(x)=1/(1+exp(-x)).